# Angular 4/2 using FormBuilder can I set place holder and label?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am developing application where all the labels for the controls are coming from a database and what I want is when I am binding form using Form Builder, to set label of that control at the same time, and use it as a place holder in that control.

Here is what I want:

```html
<label class="control-label col-md-2">
  {from form builder property}
</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" 
      formControlName="LName" 
      class="form-control" 
      placeholder="{from form builder property}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do it in angular 4/2?

Comment: `{{myForm.controls.myControl.value}}` if you do have such an control in your form.

Comment: I think it will give value of the control not the label of the control. Am i right?

Comment: Yes it will.  you want to display the name of the control, correct? Sorry, misunderstood :)

Comment: yes name is configurable by user so..

Comment: So are you looking for something akin to message bundles from Java? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/after.html in Angular? In that case they normally have external properties files for i18n

Comment: Because otherwise, just outputting using {{ }} syntax will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add placeholder/label value to a `FormControl` so you can't access thm in you template..

Just get it from the object you retrieve from the server:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2">
  {{ data.fieldLabel }}
</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" 
      formControlName="LName" 
      class="form-control" 
      [placeholder]="data.fieldPlaceholder" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or an other way is to use the nice [ng-formly](https://github.com/formly-js/ng-formly) module to build you forms only from JSON objects without coding templates.